# How to prove if there exist unique $u$ and $w$ such that for any $v$, $v=u+w$, then $V$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I prove the statement: if there exist unique $u$ and $w$ such that for any $v$, $v=u+w$, then $V$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $W$? ($U,W,V$ are vector spaces, $u \in U, w \in W, v \in V$)

I have this vague feeling that I should negate the conclusion and show a contradiction occurs, but it's not so easy for me. How do I expand the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (exterior) direct sum $U \oplus W$ of $U$ and $W$ is the set $U \times W$, with operations by components.

The uniqueness of decomposition tells you that the map
$$
V \to U \oplus W
$$
given by
$$
u + w \mapsto (u, w)
$$
is **well-defined**. That this is then an isomorphism follows in a straightforward matter.

Alternatively, define a map
$$
U \oplus W \to V
$$
by
$$
(u, w) \mapsto u + w.
$$
This time there is no problem of well-definition, as each element of $U \oplus W$ can be written uniquely as $(u, w)$. The map is immediately seen to be linear. The fact that you can write all elements of $V$ as $u + w$ tells you that this map is surjective. The fact that you can write them **uniquely** so, tells you the map is injective, as $u + w = 0 = 0 + 0$ iff $u = w = 0$ by uniqueness, so the kernel is $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: this helped a lot, thank you so much!